# "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix." + two line list item and string_array

Tags: android, parsing, arrays

Below is my `Activity_Main.xml` code from an Eclipse APP I am trying to build.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:background="@id/twoLineListItem1"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:contentDescription="@string/shop"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <TwoLineListItem
    android:id="@+id/twoLineListItem1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="134dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    **android:entries="@string_array/SHOP"**
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

At

```
TwoLineListItem I am getting an "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix."
 in the android:entries line (in bold).
```

I have a string array SHOP xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <string-array name = "shop">
      <item android:id="@+id/IKEA"
      android:icon="@drawable/IKEA"
      android:title="@STRING/IKEA" />
    <item android:id="@+id/ILVA"
      android:icon="@drawable/ILVA"
      android:title="@STRING/ILVA" />   
    <item android:id="@+id/SILVAN"
      android:icon="@drawable/SILVAN"
      android:title="@STRING/SILVAN" />
  </string-array>
  </menu>
```

I have tried a couple of things that I found on the net but none work.  Pretty confident that the issue is with the way the string_array statement is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `string-array` syntax has problems:

- It should not be in a `menu` but in a `resources` elemement.
- `string-array` `item`s don't require any attributes. This is probably some copy-paste artifact from the `menu`.
- You refer to `string-array` resources with `@array/name`, not `@string-array/name`.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

The code you posted doesn't exactly produce the error message you claim. That could be reproduced e.g. if the attribute namespace `android` was mistyped, or the namespace wasn't declared at all with `xmlns:android="..."`.

Comment: Hi Iaalto,
Thank you for the reply.
not sure I understand this part:
 •It should not be in a menu but in a resources elemement.
AS far as I can tell the XML file is part of resources as menu is under resources - unless you mean that I should replace Menu with Resources element in the actual XML code?
Thank you for the attachment and your help.

Comment: See the linked documentation. In the example, the root eleement is `<resources>`.

Comment: Hi Iaalto,
the issue withe the string-array seems to be solved I did have a strings.xml but with wrong data so it just needed some tweaking.
The link is excellent,having new error with icon and title in my shop xml but want to check the docs before submitting a new question.
Thanks for your help.